# Syntax highlighter with selective attribute highlight - VS Addin

Tags: visual-studio-2008, add-in, qt-vs-addin

Is there any VS Adding for highlighting particular code block or attribute from whole code ?

Thanks,
Piyush

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a thing which can help you - **Visual Assist X** addIn from http://www.wholetomato.com/. It has many features, including highlighting a symbol under cursor (if I understand your question correctly):

[image]